# How do I find the highest integer directly after a regex pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm writing a bash script which will cURL all version numbers starting with 1. with the subversion above 10. It gets this from an RSS page and print them on a new line using a combo of awk grep and a regex.

```
curl -v --silent https://website.com.rss 2>&1 | awk -F '<title>|<\/title>' '{print $2}' | grep "^1\.[0-9][0-9]\."
```

The command above produces:

```
1.10.1
1.10.2
1.10.3
1.11.1
1.11.2
1.11.4
```

I am trying to get the output to display only the highest sub sub version for each sub version. For example, from the output above I want to only get:

```
1.10.3
1.11.4
```

as they're both the latest release for the respective sub version.

I'm not really sure how I could achieve this or if it's even possible. I assume i'd need a loop to look through each with potentially another regex but I'm stumped. Any advice?

Comment: No It is not possible with Regex. Regex is not a comparing tool it is a pattern matching. You will need to break down this numbers and compare it as numbers.

Comment: I don't not what you are trying, however, PHP has a neat `version_compare` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) - it is probably installed on a host near you.

Comment: I think you can do all the job in awk without grep but your regex ? I get awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'. So your FS is '<title>|</title>' and you never catch '<\/title>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk (using @sergio's data):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}
$3 > a[$1 "." $2] { 
    a[$1 "." $2]=$3
}
END {
    for(i in a) 
        print i,a[i]
}' file
1.10.3                                                                          
1.11.4                                                                          
1.12.13                                                                         
1.13.4
```

Output order is awk `for` default, ie. appears random.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for giving me another way to do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could save the output of your command in a file (e.g. `inputfile.txt`). For example:

```
1.10.1                                                                          
1.11.1                                                                          
1.11.2                                                                          
1.10.3                                                                          
1.13.2                                                                          
1.12.3                                                                          
1.11.4                                                                          
1.12.3                                                                          
1.12.1                                                                          
1.12.13                                                                         
1.10.2                                                                          
1.13.1                                                                          
1.13.4
```

Then use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

max=0                                                                           
i=0                                                                             
lines=($(sort -t. -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 inputfile.txt))                         
version=${lines[0]/??/}                                                         
version=${version/.*/}                                                          
for line in ${lines[@]}; do                                                     
    tmp=${line/??/}                                                
    tmp=${tmp/.*/}                                                              
    if [ $tmp -eq $version ]; then                                              
        if (( ${line//./} > $max )); then                                       
            max=${line//./}                                                     
        fi                                                                      
    else                                                                        
        echo ${lines[i-1]}                                                      
    fi                                                                          
    version=$tmp                                                                
    ((i++))                                                                     
done                                                                            
echo $line
```

This will output the highest sub sub version for each sub version:

```
1.10.3                                                                                  
1.11.4                                                                                  
1.12.13                                                                                 
1.13.4
```

I assumed that each line starts with a single digit followed by a dot. If this is not the case (for example `11.10.1`) then the line `tmp=${line/??/}` needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You don't nee awk piped to grep piped to another awk - just 1 awk command will do:

```
awk -F '</?title>' '
{
    split($2,f,/[.]/)
    ver       = f[1]
    subVer    = f[2]
    subSubVer = f[3]
}
(ver == 1) && (subVer >= 10) {
    key = ver "." subVer
    maxSsv[key] = (subSubVer > maxSsv[key] ? subSubVer : maxSsv[key])
}
END {
    for (key in maxSsv) {
        print key "." maxSsv[key]
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you like to utilize regex, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A max

while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) ]]; then
        sub=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        subsub=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        if [[ -z "${max[$sub]}" || ${max[$sub]} -lt $subsub ]]; then
            max[$sub]=$subsub
        fi
    fi
done < inputfile.txt

for sub in ${!max[@]}; do
    printf "%d.%d.%d\n" 1 $sub ${max[$sub]}
done
```

where inputfile.txt holds the lines of verion numbers.